# Bandwidth usage cap on free plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase on a free plan (I don’t have billing enabled). As far as I’m aware, free users get 30gb of bandwidth per month. I was wondering if google would cap the bandwidth usage when I reach that limit of if I would continue using bandwidth and end up having to pay for it. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm asking about Firestore, not Cloud Storage

Comment: Firestore doesn't have a monthly 30gb bandwidth limit.  Cloud Storage does, but it's metered daily.  Are you sure you're looking at the correct product and associated data on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a free plan, if you reach a quota you get cut off, not charged. If you're on the blaze plan (with billing enabled), you get charged for usage over quotas.

However for Firestore, I can't imagine you hitting the bandwidth limit before you hit the read/write limit. Are you sure you're not talking about Firebase Realtime Database? (different product than Firebase Firestore)

Comment: I just started using firebase so maybe I'm not understanding, but auto-billing on firebase's free flan is all I needed to know about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The naming is a bit confusing, but Firebase has 2 different databases you can use: Firestore or Realtime Database. They use different data models and pricing schemes. Here's a page describing the differences: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: I can confirm I am using Firestore. I would also like to add that the billing page says the following about spark plans: "The resources available to you in the Spark plan are capped. If your project exceeds a limit, services may be disabled for that product."
 Thanks for all of your help!